# error 404 trying to install azure-iothub-device-client

Tags: azure-iot-hub

Hey guys im traying to connect my Raspberry pi 3 with azure iot hub.
Im using a Scrip with Python 3.8 and here emerge the problem

Python use this library "azure-iot-hub" to connect the device to Azure iot

When i install the library the link doesn't work
i´ve tried several links from pip but its impossible to install, allways i have the same problem:

$s sudo pip install azure-iothub-device-client

Looking in indexes: https://pypi.org/simple, https://www.piwheels.org/simpl
Collecting azure-iothub-device-client
Could not install packages due to and EnvironmentError: 404 Client Error: Not found for url: https://pypi.org/simple/azure-iothub-device-client/

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QLsrR.jpg)

Comment: If you add the content of those images as text instead of a photo taken with your phone, it helps others find you an answer. It's hard to read right now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

azure-iothub-device-client is a deprecated library and is not being updated. You should be using azure-iot-device instead.

Reference Link:

https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdk-python/issues/752